# How to make row of elements centered with flexible width

Tags: css, centering

http://jsfiddle.net/c3tGR/

I want these elements to be centered, but with variable number of items per row based on the width of the window.. so on a wide window you'd have all 5 side by side, centered; on a narrower one you'd have 3 on the first row and 2 on the second, but each row is centered.

Is there any way to do this with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Add a parent block and give it `text-align: center`, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3tGR/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Put this on the parent

```
text-align: center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c3tGR/2/